# Can abstract classes have implementation in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

The compiler doesn't seem to mind it so far but I just wanted to double check whether I'm setting myself up for failure in any way by implementing certain methods in my abstract class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An abstract class usually has one or more abstract method. So yes it can have some method implemented. The goal is to force the user to implement these methods to have an object working. Sometimes abstract classes are used to provide a 'base' implementation of some interfaces, leaving the final user to specify just the key methods. You can also have an abstract class without any abstract method: in this case you are asserting you must derive from that class in order to use it.

Comment: Is possible to create abstract class without abstract methods, simply marking class as abstract...

Comment: abstract class means it must be inherited to be instantiated. Doesn't imply it should have abstract methods as  Kirill Polishchuk noted.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Thank you Krill, I never noticed that, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 11):

It's common to have some implementation in abstract classes.

If there is no implementation at all, consider using an interface instead of an abstract class.

Answer (score 4):

Perfectly fine to implement some methods and leave others abstract.

If all methods had to be abstract, you might as well use an interface for it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `abstract` class cannot be instantiated (you have to instantiate a class *that inherits from your abstract class*), but it can contains implementations.

Answer (score 3):

it's fine and allowed, an `abstract class` has at least a member (method/property) not implemented so it cannot be instantiated.

an `interface` is also called `pure abstract class` which means it's 100% abstract, so does not allow you to specify any implementation.

keep in mind that there are lots of articles and opinions about never deriving a concrete class from another concrete class but only from abstract ones... at least this was the trend in C++ up to some years ago, then I moved to the C# side, started working more and had no time to keep reading those nice articles... :)

Comment: You can have an abstract class without any abstract member in C#